# Show div based on drop down option

Tags: javascript, angular2-template, lookup, ng-show

I have a component with a  drop down is currently returning several options. I want to add the functionality that when the option 'other' is chosen, a div will *show*. I'm not sure how to write the check for the case of 'other.'

Here is the code so far:

```js
  <div class="p-2 col">
    <select class="form-control w-100" type="checkbox" formControlName="paidToId">
      <option *ngFor="let lookupItem of leHudItemInfo.availablePaidTos" [ngValue]="lookupItem.id">
        {{lookupItem.name}}
        
        //this returns the options, but how can I add a flag for only the string of "other"
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

```html
   <div class="showOther" ng-show="paidToOptions=='other'">
      </div>
```

HTML:`<div class="" ng-show="selection=='other'">
      </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Boolean variables. If the user selects "other", set the variable to true. Then use it as a value to show or hide your div.

```
var otherOption = true; //set the value using the dropdown
```

Then in your html:

```
<div class="showOther" [hidden]={!otherOption}></div>
```

By the way, if you're using Angular2+, you can't use `ng-show`. The equivalent can be `[hidden]` or `*ngIf`.

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for the comment about angular2 :) I am still new to it!